# Is “curiouser” in fact a word (like in the famous phrase “curiouser and curiouser”)?

Tags: meaning, etymology, is-it-a-word, comparatives, register

Is *curiouser*, in fact, a word?

Answer (score 29):

In Standard English, this is not a properly formed word; the standard form is "more curious".

As a general principle, the comparative *-er* suffix attaches to monosyllabic words, and *more* is preferred with polysyllabic words, so even though a word like *curiouser* is readily understood, it has an odd quality to it — this is the reason.

According to the [OED](http://oed.com), the word *curiouser* was coined by Lewis Carroll in [Alice in Wonderland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_in_Wonderland) in 1865, as the phrase "curiouser and curiouser".  In fact, the OED cites this phrase only, and does not treat *curiouser* as a word unto itself; the phrase has the meaning "increasingly strange".  With this in mind, you might be able to justify the use of the entire *phrase* in a formal context (depending on your audience).

---

**Addendum:** Let me just state (for the record) that if you are wondering if this would be considered a word in the pure linguistic sense (rather than in Standard English), then I think that most linguists would say yes; it probably has been around long enough and is well-established enough to be considered a word.

Comment: So "Even curiouser, the..." is not justifiable?  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @GnomeSlice: Probably not justifiable if the reader is pedantic. But really, it depends on your audience.  The example you just gave does recall the original phrase, but as it is not the original phrase, might have a higher chance of being frowned upon if your audience is picky or highly formal.

Comment: This comes perilously close to prescriptivism. I think using a word figuratively, coining a usage or using an exotic usage, is fair game. If Charles Lutwidge Dodgson can do it, why can't @GnomeSlice?

Comment: @Robusto: It's not prescriptivism to tell someone the facts about how a word or phrase may or may not be perceived, and allow them to make their own judgment about their audience. If GnomeSlice told me he was writing a fiction novel, then I'd tell him absolutely to use the word. If he told me he was writing an academic paper, I'd advise him to avoid it.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Well, it depends on whether he can carry it off or not. A good writer can use any word he chooses and make it work. And speaking of academic papers, I actually used this very phrase — "Curiouser and curiouser" — in a graduate-level English paper, without attribution or even quotes. Grade? A+.

Comment: I put it in a question on Superuser.com, and someone edited it out.  It just made me wonder if it wasn't really a word.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/244093/wireless-mouse-behaving-improperly-in-flash   For reference.

Comment: @Robusto: I have been saying that you need to consider your audience. Obviously an English paper (which is about literature, and this quote is from literature) is a different animal!  Furthermore, in a classroom assignment, you have an audience of one, whom you have formed a relationship with — so you can judge the reader very specifically. I don't think your advice that "a good writer can use any word he chooses and make it work" is good general advice for a typical academic paper. But it is good advice for someone trying to creatively push the limits of the language.

Comment: @Robusto, @Kosmonaut: “A good writer can use any word he chooses and make it work” seems tautologically true — one of the things that makes a good writer good is that she won’t choose a word that won’t work :-P  But on the whole I’d agree with it, and actually, especially for an academic paper: there, you and your audience have a lot of shared background and culture, so if you want to bend or invent a meaning, they’ll probably be able to follow you.  I’d feel it’s in writing for a wider, less predictable audience that being playful and idiosyncratic is less likely to be effective.

Comment: @GnomeSlice: whoever edited it out has had either a humourectomy or an overzealous English teacher at some point.

Comment: @PLL: but if there are words that don't work, the good writer *can't* choose those words and make them work...

Comment: @PLL you get a +1 on that comment just for the "humourectomy" ;-) (Of course, I'd spell it "humorectomy"...)

Comment: @pll A humourectomy sounds dangerously similar to exsanguination.

Comment: @PLL I would rather think they did not read novels. 

Answer (score 5):

**Not quite**, apart from in the specific phrase “curiouser and curiouser”, taken from [Alice in Wonderland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_in_Wonderland).  Lewis Carroll was playing with language there.

The *-er* ending is almost never used with words of more than two syllables: so eg *more beautiful*, *more curious*, not usually *?beautifuller*, *?curiouser*.

**Edit:** the OED agrees — it doesn’t list *curiouser* as a word or a form of *curious*, but does list *curiouser and curiouser* as a phrase.

Comment: I know it's *almost* never used, so that's why I took the time to ask.  Thanks for the answer.  It's a shame really, I rather liked the word.  :(

Comment: @GnomeSlice: then use it! :-P  There are no language police who will arrest you.  As long as your meaning is clear, and you’re confident enough to convince other people that you’re doing it playfully rather than making a mistake, you can use any words you want. The dictionary of tomorrow is written by the imaginative speakers of today…

Comment: That's my point. You can play with language and get away with it. Since when does language have to be hidebound and dour?

Comment: @GnomeSlice: Be glad you aren't a French speaker — [they *do* have language police](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)!

Comment: @Robusto: yes, I agree with that point.  But there’s a fair spectrum between “nowhere near being a word” (*\*zorgblax*), “could easily become a word, but isn’t one yet” (*?Robustoism*), and “yep, it’s a word!” (*yesteryear*).  *Curiouser* is very close to the finish line… but at least arguably, it’s not quite there yet. I guess widespread usage independent of a specific phrase is probably the main criterion I’m going on here, with dictionary inclusion being an authoritative measure of that.  Maybe **not quite** or **not yet** would have been a better way to begin my answer :-)

Comment: Lewis Carroll is quite known for deliberately fooling around with the English language, though.

Answer (score 3):

*Curiouser* isn't the standard form of the [expression](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expression?s=t) in English; the equivalent standard form is *more curious*.

To elaborate, as a general rule the comparative *-er* and the superlative *-est* suffixes don't attach to adjectives of more than two syllables — the modifiers *more* and *most* are preferred pretty much exclusively — so even though a word like *curiouser* is readily understood, it sounds odd.

This may have been the original point of it. The [OED](http://oed.com) addresses the phrase *curiouser and curiouser* within the entry for *curious*, citing as its origin Lewis Carroll's [Alice in Wonderland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_in_Wonderland) (1865), which is a notoriously whimsical text. The OED doesn't treat the bare word *curiouser* as an expression unto itself; rather, it gives the meaning of the entire phrase *curiouser and curiouser* as "more and more curious; increasingly strange". Note that it defines the phrase with the standard form of expression *more curious*. But given the entry, you might be able to justify the use of the entire phrase in a formal context, depending on your audience, if not the bare word.

Of course *curiouser* is a [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word) in the pure linguistic sense, however, and clearly it's a word with its own meaning even as it takes part in Alice's phrase. And the fact that it doesn't accord with standard English construction and usage doesn't at all stop everyone from using it. Indeed, along with the entire original phrase, it seems to have entered the collective discourse, if not especially frequently, and still retaining the some of the whimsicality of the original instance. Witness the following:

- *Mickey thought* curiouser *was a noun, something that made you more curious. That's what made up my mind about the title. Wouldn't it be great if people listened to this album and it made them curiouser?* — [Kate Miller-Heidke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiouser)
- *Benford’s Law: A curious statistical phenomenon that keeps getting curiouser* — [Ted Hill](http://blog.press.princeton.edu/2015/10/06/benfords-law-a-curious-statistical-phenomenon-that-keeps-getting-curiouser/)

The great thing about *couriouser* is its self-referential performativity. It's a strange word that means *strange*.

Even odder, though, is *curiousest*, which may help shed some light on the "problem" with *couriouser*. I would venture that *couriousest*, being the couriouser of the two words, is hardly ever used.

**Note:** Thanks to [Kosmonaut](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/449/kosmonaut) for starting this answer off. I tried simply to make an edit to Kosmonaut's answer, but my edit was rejected as too different, so I posted the edited version as a separate answer. Since then I've revised it further.

Answer (score 2):

It is because Lewis Caroll says it is:

> “Curiouser and curiouser!” Cried Alice (she was so much surprised, that for the moment she quite forgot how to speak good English). “Now I’m opening out like the largest telescope that ever was! Good-bye, feet!” (for when she looked down at her feet they seemed to be almost out of sight, they were getting so far off). “Oh, my poor little feet, I wonder who will put on your shoes and stockings for you now, dears? I’m sure I shan’t be able! I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself about you: you must manage the best way you can—but I must be kind to them,” thought Alice, “or perhaps they won’t walk the way I want to go! Let me see. I’ll give them a new pair of boots every Christmas.”

Comment: @GnomeSlice: “technically” is an exceedingly slippery concept in English, since we have no equivalent of eg the Académie Française claiming to define what’s officially correct.  Dictionaries *describe* what the language is, they don’t *define* it — whether something is a word or not depends on how widely used and understood it is, so is a quantitative and often highly debatable question.

Comment: @GnomeSlice: If you're a good writer, you can choose your words from a larger palette. You don't have to be constrained. that's all I'm saying.

Comment: note that although alice uses the word she is also described as not using good english.

Comment: "When I use a word, it means exactly what I want it to mean, neither more not less!" - Humpty Dumpty, in *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*".

Comment: @Colin Fine: Mr. Dumpty actually appeared in *Through the Looking-Glass*.

Comment: @jk01: I made no guarantees as to the quality of the word. I merely said that it *is* a word. Lotta people can't take a joke around here.

Comment: @mmyers: Of course you're right. What *was* I thinking of?

Comment: It *is* a word. Not because Lewis Caroll said it is, obviously, since immediately after having Alice use the word, he points out that she had *quite forgot how to speak good English*. It becomes a word when people use it *without* reference to that "original". Which I'm sure has happened many times, but I'll just quote *New Scientist* 25 June 2011, page 4, where the first paragraph starts **It's no surprise [blah blah]. What is curiouser [blah blah blah]**. The *writer* probably knew of the "original", but there's no allusion to it in the text, nor will all *readers* know of it. It's a word.

Answer (score 2):

Today's description is tomorrow's prescription. Italian is really really poor Latin (which of course is really really poor something-that-came-before-it), and at the same time each has its rulebook.

'Curiouser' was malformed at the time Lewis Carroll coined it, and that's part of the linguistic humor of it. 'Chortle' was also one of his neologisms and nowadys I think it is accepted as a 'real word.

As to 'curiouser' I think currently it still sounds strange (because of the (non-prescriptive) inherent English rule that in general multisyllabic adjectives get their comparative via 'more X' rather than 'Xer'. But if you repeat it enough (and others repeat it enough), it may become more standard.

So in SE standards/culture, using 'curiouser' might be coonsidered a bit too ... informal.

Answer (score -1):

I'm certainly not the smartest person on this board from what I've read so far, but 'Curiouser' sounds like it would fall quite nicely under the definition of NEOLOGISM, (i.e., a term, word, or phrase that may be in the process of entering common use but that has not yet been accepted into mainstream language...and is often directly attributable to a specific person, publication, period or event). But it could also be a SEMANTIC EXTENSION, which is basically an already existing word with a new twist. But really it comes down to IDIOLECT, your own personal dialect and vocabulary which you choose to use.

Comment: It is neither a neologism nor semantic extension, no. If anything, it's a somewhat unusual form of analogy (which is not surprising, given its humorous origin).